# launchSettings "commandName": "Docker" - what exactly does it do?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

Visual studio can create a project from template with "enable Docker support". In which a section in launchSettings.json is created with

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "publishAllPorts": true
}
```

When started with this configuration, what I see is that docker image is built and started in Docker Desktop and debugging is started in a remote debugging fashion (I see no dotnet instance started locally)
My question:

- Are my assumptions correct?
- Is there any documentation that describe thoese behaviour and where we can tweak these settings, such as targeting a remote docker host?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/launch-profiles?view=vs-2022